# Importing distant modules in javascript from unpkg

Tags: javascript, import

I’m trying to import whole modules in a javascript file.

This file pertains to the Home Assistant environment where the frontend is written in javascript, usually using LitElements and modules (cf. [documentation](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/frontend/custom-ui/lovelace-custom-card/)).

For instance, the doc uses a fancy `wired-card` by writing:

```
import "https://unpkg.com/wired-card@0.8.1/wired-card.js?module";.
```

I've read a lot about the `import` call but resources are usually about local elements and it seems that I need them to be distant.

In fact, I know the plain old JS quite well but I am a bit clueless regarding importing modules (and LitElements for that matter).

For instance, I'm looking for an accordion (expansion panel), like [the one of JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/). I found several resources (e.g. [here](https://github.com/IvanSkokovskyi/lit-element-accordion), [here](https://unpkg.com/browse/carbon-components@10.25.0/), or [here](https://unpkg.com/browse/angular-material-expansion-panel@0.7.2/)) but I couldn't find how to import them easily.

What makes a module importable? Are those not or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In standard ECMAscript, a JS file is importable if it defines a module in the new system. Kinda circular.

Basically, it should export some resources from the module file. For example, if I have a `test-module.js`, I can export some class using the `export` keyword:

```js
class Fubar {}

export { Fubar }

// or, more concisely

export class Fubar {}
```

The `export` keyword tells the module system that the resource defined should be made available to importers.

On the flip side, if you want to import a module, you must also do so from a module! This is because module imports are async and processed before the execution (excluding the dynamic `import()` function).

So, if I want to import my `Fubar` class from another module, I can do this:

```
import { Fubar } from './test-module.js`
```

However, if I load this script as a non-module, I will get an error. Instead, I must tell the browser that the script is a module:

```
<script type="module" src="test-module.js"></script>
```

So, in short, something is "importable" if it is itself a module.

More reading:

- Mozilla Dev Network article on the modules system: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules
- MDN article on the `import` keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

EDIT: something I missed - to make web resources a little nicer, the import URLs can be any URL, not just a relative path. This allows importing 3rd party scripts as modules. But, those 3rd party scripts need to be modules themselves.